# Is this statement about power series true?

Tags: power-series

Write $P(x; a) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n$. 
Is there a way to show that there exists a choice of nonzero sequence $a_n$ for which $P(x_k; a) = 0$ for $k = 1, \dots, n$, and $x_1, \dots, x_n \in \mathbf{R}$?

More generally, suppose $X \subset \mathbf{R}$, when is

$$\{
a \in \mathbf{R}^\mathbf{N} \setminus \{0\} \mid P(x; a) = 0, \mbox{for all}~x \in X
\}
$$
nonempty? (I know that when $X$ contains a neighborhood of 0.)

Comment: Are you asking if you can construct a non-trivial polynomial  (or prove that such a polynomial exists) that has zeros at $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n\}$?  $P(x) =  a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)$

Comment: Yes, apparently I was. doh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, consider the polynomial
$$
f(x) = \prod_{i = 1}^n (x - x_i)
$$
This polynomial will have a finite power series expansion
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_n x^n
$$
which, because it is finite, will converge everywhere. Note that this is nothing but the statement that $f$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $n$.

As to your second question, it is a fact from complex analysis that if $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has a limit point in $\mathbb{R}$, then the power series must be identically $0$. In other words, the set, as you've defined it, is empty.

As far as I know, when $X$ doesn't have a limit point, anything can happen.

Comment: The last case is covered by [Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Existence_of_entire_function_with_specified_zeroes).

Comment: Wow, obviously the coefficients of $f$ are nonzero. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for rest of the information.